# array access won't increment in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, increment

I'm trying to update the first column in a table with new values, using something like what I've got below..
the problem is that the $userTemp variable  is not incrementing in mysql but it seems to run through the elements in an array (as expected) within a php for loop. however in mysql_query this does not seem to be reflecting? I don't quite understand why as when I echo $userTemp before the mysql_query it shows that it is incrementing correctly. the query is run through the function queryMysqlPopulate($userTemp,$row[0]); but the argument does not seem to get passed to the function. however after the function call running another echo for $userTemp shows that the value has infact incremented.
like seriously?! please could someone enlighten me as to why? does session control have something to do with this?

any help is greatly appreciated!

PS. this is not the full program I've just snipped the parts that are applicable, so as not to take up too much of your time (hope that helps).

```
$userlogins = array('c001','d001','dj001','ed001',
                'k001','nr001','ol001','pt001',
                'py001','rx001','s005');

if (tableExists('mytable'))
{

    $tempQuery = queryMysql("SELECT username FROM students");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($tempQuery);
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $numRows ; ++$j)
        {
            $userTemp = "$userlogins[$j]";
            echo $userTemp;
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($tempQuery);
            queryMysqlPopulate($userTemp,$row[0]);
            echo $userTemp;
        }
}
```

and the function

```
function queryMysqlPopulate($tempLogin, $tempRow){

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET username='$tempLogin' WHERE username='$tempRow'") or die(mysql_error());
return $result;}
```

i can't answer my own question cause i#M a newbie :P
 so edit insteaD:

No problems this works fine, although it's not exactly what i was looking for as it's not exactly array access, but explicitly referring to a field by it's value :(

```
for($i = 0; $i < $loops; ++$i)
    {
        queryMysql("INSERT INTO $name VALUES" .
        "('hi$i', 'there', 'all', 'you', 'cats')");
    }
```

then changing update ...set to

```
if (tableExists('mytable'))
{

    $tempQuery = queryMysql("SELECT username FROM mytable");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($tempQuery);
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $numRows ; ++$j)
        {
            $userTemp = "$userlogins[$j]";
            echo $userTemp;
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($tempQuery);
            queryMysqlPopulate($userTemp,'hi'.$j);
            echo $userTemp;
            //echo $row[0];

        }
    //echo tableExists('none');
    }
```

I'd still prefer to do this by array access i.e. accessing the first field of the first column by element number in the update ... set mysql query. so any help with that is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly you select the current user into a session.

Comment: You need to give us your mysql table stucture.
Preferably like this:
USE myDBname;
CREATE TABLE students
(StudNo integer not null  AUTO_INCREMENT  primary key, 
StudFirstName VARCHAR(140),  
StudSurname VARCHAR(140),  
StudUsername VARCHAR(140),
CustPW VARCHAR(100)
);

Comment: Please don;t use functions for now.
Take Example2 procedural style. Easier to understand:
 [www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Take a look at my example, maybe it helps. I use customers as users.
 [https://www.facebook.com/download/1455490241343709/InvoicePHPmysql.zip](https://www.facebook.com/download/1455490241343709/InvoicePHPmysql.zip)

Comment: I recommend using the improved mysqli instead of mysql. mysql is abandoned in PHP version 5.5